# Backspacing specific words to previous line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

For my job, we have a lot of clients who accidentally use embedded returns in the systems they use which show up wonky in the raw data on our side. It causes an extra line to show, which we need to fix nefore we can load. This can be really time consuming. The issue is, sometimes when we search words in Notepad++, it will also show results for words that are fine.

I've researched and cant find a way to find lines with single specific words, and literally have those lines move or backspace into the previous line above it. For example, if we search the word "BR":

```
Title1      Title2            Title3
060001      Random Text       Random Text BR Random Text Random Text
BR

060002     Random Text       Random Text BR Random Text Random Text BR
```

The BR in Title3 column is fine, but Title1 should only have numbers. I'm thinking if I can

1. Search the keyword "BR" that has nothing before and after it, and
2. Have the whole line literally backspace?

Honestly, I've never dealt with notepad++ before this job so I dont have much experience, but I looked around and can't find if this is something that can be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?=\S+$)`
- Replace with:   <-- A space
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak
(?=         # positive lookahea, make sure we have after:
    \S+       # 1 or more any non space character
    $         # end of line
)           #end lookahead
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]